# How can I get 'Recent Items' object Ids in Apex (soql) is it possible

Tags: apex

'Recent Items' pane shows recently viewed records for the selected tab. The list is derived from your recent items and includes records owned by you and other users.

[image]

Is there any way to get this in apex?

Comment: I see the question is specifically about apex, but it is possible to get the recent items list via the REST API. Worst case you could pull it in that way.

Comment: @DanielBallinger can you please eloborate on how to get the recent items via REST API? Just curious cos getting the data is the critical part storing and reporting would be easier

Comment: Daniel Hoechst's answer should be marked as the best way, as this is now possible from SOQL / Apex using the `RecentlyViewed` object introduced in Summer 13. This is by far a better solution than doing a REST API callout, which consumes API Calls and can only be done by users with the 'API Enabled' permission.

Comment: @zachelrath I agree, I changed answer now, so that others can benefit from it now. Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a new object available in Summer '13 called [RecentlyViewed](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_referencepre/Content/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm) that you can use in SOQL to get a user's recently viewed records.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM RecentlyViewed 
WHERE Type IN ('Account', 'Contact')
ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
```

Comment: I have been waiting for this object in SOQL for years. At last! At last! However, you don't seem to be able to do sub-queries on this object yet, which is quite a significant limitation when you want to return fields other than Name. The following query, for instance, does not work: `select CustomField1__c, CustomField2__c from Account where Id in (select Id from RecentlyViewed where Type = 'Account')`

Comment: I tried run this query and notice it return different result from RecentItem.Check my question here.Is there any specific setting that I need to do?http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91612/query-recentlyviewed-return-different-result-from-recent-item

Comment: RecentlyViewed do not capture records data that are accessed from the communities by the external users?

Answer (score 34):

It isn't a native Apex solution, but you can use the REST API to pull the recent items.

Using the Workbench try:
https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v26.0/recent&autoExec=1

[image]

Here is the Code (how to call it from Apex and it works) -

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setEndPoint('https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/recent');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
String jsonInput = response.getBody();
system.debug('===>'+jsonInput);
```

Here is output from Debug log

```
DEBUG|===>[{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006J00000048UO9IAM"},"Id":"006J00000048UO9IAM","Name":"Tel TEST_OPP New Business"}]
```

Comment: The URI seems to be working fine without the &autoExec=1. Where is the documentation for these kind of features? It's like finding wrap zone in mario :}Update : (never mind I googled and found the link ) :http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_discoveryresource.htm

Comment: Truly awesome, one to remember !

Comment: What!! When did this come about?  I've wanted this for ages

Comment: @Daniel - you are awesome .. made my day :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks for expanding the answer with the sample REST call. I think the `&autoExec=1` is Workbench specific.

Comment: are we able to sort lastvieweddate from here?I didn't see lastvieweddate return in json.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it in Apex (or are after generic solution) then [Daniel's idea](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4244/799) looks awesome!

I've been thinking about this problem few weeks ago but came up with some really crazy answers (screenscraping of a tab with recent items; analysis of URL you get when you click a lookup window and by default it shows recently viewed items...). Messy.

There's one Visualforce possibility I came up with so I'm going to left it here, maybe will be of use for anybody? You could experiment with `<apex:enhancedList>`, `filterId` and views that are built into your org and which strangely you can't modify or delete. I'm talking about "Recently Viewed Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities"... No idea how they're done, magic ;)

Answer (score 0):

With summer 13 a new metadata object containing the information for the recent items is introduced. The metadata object name is Recently viewed.

Query this object u will get the id' of the items directly which  are recently accessed. Otherdetails like when it is accessed is also available.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM RecentlyViewed 
WHERE Type IN ('Account', 'Contact', 'Plan__c')
ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
```

For some more examples:
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm

My Problem is that you can only fetch the current User recent Items and not all Users..