# Emulate a custom object's “Recent Items” in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, api

How can I get a **specific object's** ‘Recent Items’ object Ids in Apex or SOQL?
Please note. I am not talking about the recent Items displayed on the homepage showing object types.

I couldn't find a way in Apex or the API to get the current user's
recently viewed records of a SObject.

I want to render a "Recent Items" list on a custom Visualforce page
that looks exactly as shown when you click a tab.

[image]

Comment: Since I can't see a way to move an answer to the original question, I'm editing this one to remove the 'shouting' and deleting the original closed question. Seems like an honest mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [Daniel Ballinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger)'s [answer to 'How to get recent items'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/how-can-i-get-recent-items-object-ids-in-apex-soql-is-it-possible), the difference is really minor:

```
/services/data/v26.0/recent
```

gives you recent items like in the sidebar. "Object-specific" are well - object specific:

```
/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account
/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity
```

etc.

[image]

Or raw output:

```
  "recentItems" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Opportunity",
      "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0067000000AH3M7AAL"
    },
    "Id" : "0067000000AH3M7AAL",
    "Name" : "University of AZ Portable Generators111"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Opportunity",
      "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0067000000AH3M1AAL"
    },
    "Id" : "0067000000AH3M1AAL",
    "Name" : "Grand Hotels Kitchen Generator"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Opportunity",
      "url" : "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0067000000AH3MEAA1"
    }...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the fact that the REST API also offers Recent Items for objects.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new object that will be available in Summer '13 called [RecentlyViewed](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_referencepre/index.htm) that you can use in SOQL to get a user's recently viewed records.