# System.JSONException with object-specific recent items

Tags: apex, json

I'm trying to display recent items for custom objects in a visualforce page, however deserializing the object-specific recent items json results in a System.JSONException.

Apex:

```
public class test_controller {

    public test_controller() {

        Http httpProtocol = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
        request.setEndPoint('https://na3.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Custom_object__c');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);     
        String jsondata = response.getBody();

        Map<String, List<Map<String, sObject>>> mapJsonObjects = (Map<String, List<Map<String, sObject>>>)
            JSON.deserialize(jsondata, Map<String, List<Map<String, sObject>>>.class);

    }
}
```

The JSON response is in this format:

```
recentItems
  attributes
    type
    url
  Id
  Name
objectDescribe
  ...
```

I started using answers* by Daniel Ballinger and eyescream to similar questions, but came against this impediment.

* See:
[How can I get 'Recent Items' object Ids in Apex (soql) is it possible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/how-can-i-get-recent-items-object-ids-in-apex-soql-is-it-possible) and 
[Emulate a custom object's “Recent Items” in a Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/emulate-a-custom-objects-recent-items-in-a-visualforce-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple parser error that's happening due to incorrect parsing function written.One way i would parse this is use the http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ and generate the class and then deserialize using the class formed .

Or perhaps i think since the JSON will give us the Type of object ,From Type field we can obtain first the Name of object from Type String using JSON parser and then deserialize using

```
 List<Account> deserializedacc = 
      (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSONString, List<Account>.class)
```

Please note still we need to extract type first from JSON then using that we can deserilaize

Comment: Loved this solution extending this I played around and created the VF page that I am posting as solution too :)!!! Officially this credit goes to you @mohit

Comment: Thanks for the great resource. I realized I also need to display recent items for three objects as one list. Should I parse the org-wide recent items and extract only needed info or is there an easier way that you know of?

Comment: The wrapper class required to parse the response will be same for all objects .I would use list.Addall() and add all in a single list .Hope this helps you .recentItems.Addall(recentItems.);

Comment: @rao Thanks for taking time to put idea to code .Upvoted your answer too.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
Page:
<apex:page controller="test_webservice">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="call service" action="{!test_controller}"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!recentItems }" var="r">
<apex:column headervalue="Recent Item ID" value="{!r.id}"/>
<apex:column headervalue="Recent Item name"><apex:outputlink value="{/!r.name}">{!r.name}</apex:outputlink></apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Class:
public class test_webservice {
public JSON2Apex serialized_obj{get;set;}
public list<json2Apex.recentItems> recentItems{get;set;}

public test_webservice(){
serialized_obj = new JSON2Apex ();
}
    public pagereference test_controller() {
        Http httpProtocol = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
        request.setEndPoint('https://**your instance**.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Custom_object__c');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);     
        String jsondata = response.getBody();
       serialized_obj = JSON2Apex.parse(jsondata);
        recentItems = serialized_obj.recentitems;

    return null;
    }

}
```

JSON TO APEX CLASS : 
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

```
public class ObjectDescribe {
    public String name;
    public String label;
    public String keyPrefix;
    public String labelPlural;
    public Boolean custom;
    public Boolean layoutable;
    public Boolean activateable;
    public Urls urls;
    public Boolean searchable;
    public Boolean deprecatedAndHidden;
    public Boolean createable;
    public Boolean updateable;
    public Boolean deletable;
    public Boolean customSetting;
    public Boolean feedEnabled;
    public Boolean mergeable;
    public Boolean queryable;
    public Boolean replicateable;
    public Boolean retrieveable;
    public Boolean undeletable;
    public Boolean triggerable;
}

public class Attributes {
    public String type;
    public String url;
}

public class Urls {
    public String s_object;
    public String describe;
    public String rowTemplate;
}

public List<RecentItems> recentItems;
public ObjectDescribe objectDescribe;

public class RecentItems {
    public Attributes attributes{get;set;}
    public String Id{get;set;}
    public String Name{get;set;}
}


public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
}

static testMethod void testParse() {
    String json = '{\"recentItems\":[{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"custom_object__c\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/a0Rd0000002QRFZEA4\"},\"Id\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFZEA4\",\"Name\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFZ\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"custom_object__c\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/a0Rd0000002QRFVEA4\"},\"Id\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFVEA4\",\"Name\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFV\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"custom_object__c\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/a0Rd0000002QRFYEA4\"},\"Id\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFYEA4\",\"Name\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFY\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"custom_object__c\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/a0Rd0000002QRFXEA4\"},\"Id\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFXEA4\",\"Name\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFX\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"custom_object__c\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/a0Rd0000002QRFWEA4\"},\"Id\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFWEA4\",\"Name\":\"a0Rd0000002QRFW\"}],\"objectDescribe\":{\"name\":\"custom_object__c\",\"label\":\"custom object\",\"keyPrefix\":\"a0R\",\"labelPlural\":\"custom object\",\"custom\":true,\"layoutable\":true,\"activateable\":false,\"urls\":{\"sobject\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c\",\"describe\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/describe\",\"rowTemplate\":\"/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/{ID}\"},\"searchable\":true,\"deprecatedAndHidden\":false,\"createable\":true,\"updateable\":true,\"deletable\":true,\"customSetting\":false,\"feedEnabled\":false,\"mergeable\":false,\"queryable\":true,\"replicateable\":true,\"retrieveable\":true,\"undeletable\":true,\"triggerable\":true}}';
    JSON2Apex obj = parse(json);
    System.assert(obj != null);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know how else you can update the list in a controlled fashion to stay within API limits? If connected to pageload, we'll surpass the limit, but I also wouldn't want to force the client to manually refresh as needed.