# Recent Items SideBar in the Service Console app

Tags: service-cloud-console

My users want to have a recent items sidebar in the Service Console app. How can do this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select r.UserRoleId, r.Type, r.Title, r.RecordTypeId, r.ProfileId, r.Phone, r.Name, r.LastViewedDate, r.LastReferencedDate, r.LastName, r.IsActive, r.Id, r.FirstName, r.Email, r.Alias From RecentlyViewed r
```

You can use the above query for version 28.0 and use this and have a custom console component developed using visualforce page .

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_components_create_page_layouts.htm
https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_components_create_app.htm

Please see above links on how to have custom console component and associate visualforce page .

Example on how to implement Recent Items

[System.JSONException with object-specific recent items](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/system-jsonexception-with-object-specific-recent-items)

[Emulate a custom object's “Recent Items” in a Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/emulate-a-custom-objects-recent-items-in-a-visualforce-page)

[How can I get 'Recent Items' object Ids in Apex (soql) is it possible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/how-can-i-get-recent-items-object-ids-in-apex-soql-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thanks Mohith! can you explain me how to use this query? you mean I need to create a Visualforce page?

Comment: There are fields on that object that will give you recently viewed record Ids .You can just use that and the ProfileId to query recent items specific to user.Or i have updated my answer and you can use REST based implementation in visualforce.Yes you need visualforce for this .

Answer (score 2):

With Winter '14, a  most recent tabs component is now available in the Salesforce Console. We'll be adding more sidebar functionality as components in the following releases.

You can find more informiton on enabling the Most Recent Tabs component here -
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_setup_most_recent.htm&language=en_US

Best,
Gautam

Answer (score -1):

This currently cannot be done out of the box.  I have run across this before and clients get very upset about this when moving tot he service cloud.  There is an idea posted that you can promote.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000isK9AAI

Comment: Looks like Mohith has a decent way to accomplish if you have development skills or access to a developer.

Comment: The solution i have will involve some coding but worth of it i must say .