# Include Recent Items in Page

Tags: visualforce, recent-item

I have visualforce page that not using standardController.I would like to include  the standard Recent Items   inside my page.

I read on question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/how-can-i-get-recent-items-object-ids-in-apex-soql-is-it-possible) ,but I can get Name ,Id etc but how can I have the link,icon same like the standard  Recent Items ?

***********Updated************

Basically, I want to copy the RecentItem in SFDC Homepage to my own visualforce Homepage.

This is view from SFDC Homepage.

[image]

I can get the same  Id and Name from RecentlyViewed object using SOQL below

```
 RecentItem  =[SELECT Id, Name  FROM RecentlyViewed ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT 10];
```

But I don't know how to get URL and icon similar with Home RecentItem.I tried with this code, but still I cannot get 'Home' applabel and relate it with RecentlyViewed in query above.

```
//This already give us the details of Id and Name in RecentItem but not URL and icon.
RecentlyViewed[] recents = [
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM RecentlyViewed
        ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
        LIMIT 10
        ];
Set<String> types = new Set<String>();
for (RecentlyViewed r : recents) {
    types.add(String.valueOf(r.Id.getSObjectType()));
    system.debug('@Checking ---'+String.valueOf(r.Id.getSObjectType()));
}

List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();
for(DescribeTabSetResult tsr : tabSetDesc) {
    String appLabel = tsr.getLabel();
      System.debug('@Checking --appLabel '+appLabel);
    //No home label available,if it available how to get url of RecentlyViewed item and its icon.
    if(appLabel=='Home'){
        List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> tabDesc = tsr.getTabs();
        System.debug('-- Tab information for the Sales app --');
        for(Schema.DescribeTabResult tr : tabDesc) {
            System.debug('@Checking getLabel: ' + tr.getLabel());
            System.debug('@Checking getColors: ' + tr.getColors());
            System.debug('@Checking getIconUrl: ' + tr.getIconUrl());
            System.debug('@Checking getIcons: ' + tr.getIcons());
            System.debug('@Checking getMiniIconUrl: ' + tr.getMiniIconUrl());
            System.debug('@Checking getSobjectName: ' + tr.getSobjectName());
            System.debug('@Checking getUrl: ' + tr.getUrl());
            System.debug('@Checking isCustom: ' + tr.isCustom());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way how create link that similar to Recent Item.

First create a wrapper class.

```
public class RecentItemWrapper{
         public Id itemId { get;set;}
         public String  objectUrl {get;set;}
         public String Name {get;set;}
  }
```

Then in get method, retrieve data from RecentlyViewed and contruct the url

```
 public List<RecentItemWrapper> getRecentItem(){

  recentItem=new List<RecentItemWrapper>();

  lstRecentItem  =[SELECT Id, Name  FROM RecentlyViewed ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT 10];

  for (RecentlyViewed r : lstRecentItem) {
      system.debug('@Checking... '+ String.valueOf(r.Id.getSObjectType()));
      Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sa = r.Id.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
      String prefixOrc = sa.getKeyPrefix();

      RecentItemWrapper wrapper = new RecentItemWrapper();
      wrapper.itemId=r.Id;
      wrapper.objectUrl=System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()+'/'+r.Id;
      wrapper.Name=r.Name;
      system.debug('@Checking objectUrl = '+ wrapper.objectUrl);
      recentItem.add(wrapper);

     }

     return recentItem;

 }
```

In Visualforce Page,code something like this:

```
  <ul>
  <apex:repeat value="{!recentItem}" var="items">
        <li><a href="{!items.objectUrl}">{!items.Name}</a> </li>
  </apex:repeat>                 
  </ul>
```

Comment: The only thing that I m not able to do is retrieve the icon, I submit the idea here.Please vote for it.If you know how to do it, let me know. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000oMy4AAE

Answer (score 0):

There is a describe call available that gives you the [mini icon URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_schema_describetabresult.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeTabResult_getMiniIconUrl) that you can add to your Visualforce e.g.:

```
https://na3.salesforce.com/img/icon/contacts16.png
```

Based on [Describing Tabs Using Schema Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeTabs.htm) it looks like you will have to search for that icon though by perhaps matching with the app label and then the [SObject name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_schema_describetabresult.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeTabResult_getSobjectName) or just searching for the SObject name.

**PS**

You can find the type of an SObject from its ID using the [Id.getSObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType) method. So to find the types:

```
RecentlyViewed[] recents = [
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM RecentlyViewed
        ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
        LIMIT 10
        ];
Set<String> types = new Set<String>();
for (RecentlyViewed r : recents) {
    types.add(String.valueOf(r.Id.getSObjectType()));
}
```

and then they can be translated into the icon URLs via the describe data.

Comment: How we can link that class with RecentlyViewed object, example I use this query SELECT Id, Name  FROM RecentlyViewed ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT 10,then how we can get the URL or icon using the value from SQL with DescribeTabResult class ?

Comment: @unidha See the PS in the answer.

Comment: I updated my trial above.Still I am struggling to link it with RecentlyViewed,I loop appLabel but didn't get 'Home' tab.If I get it,is it possible to get the 10 items in RecentlyViewed object?

Comment: @unidha I suggest you match on the `tr.getSobjectName()` and remove the `tsr.getLabel()` match.

Comment: thanks for fast reply.I notice RecentlyViewed object not covered by tab object.Refer to my code here:gist.github.com/unidha/db3c91dcfb8a42d74bb2 .In RecentlyViewed I retrieved Account,ListView and User but from DescribeTab I only retrieve Account.